# Discontinuity cumulative function of dirac

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let's say I have cumulative function of dirac measures $F_{\delta_{a_n}}(x)$ that converge pointwise to $F(x)$ for all $x$ such that $F$ is continuous (which is also a cumulative function).

Now  $F_{\delta_{a_n}}(x)=0$ or $F_{\delta_{a_n}}(x)=1$ so that $F(x)=0$ or $F(x)=1.$

> Does $F$ have only one discontinuous point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the contrary: There exists $x<y$ such that $F$ is discontinuous at $x$ and $y$.

As $F$ is monotone and right-continuous, it follows $F(x) < F(y)$. Since $F$ has countably many discontinuities only, there exists some $c\in (x, y)$ such that $F$ is continuous at $c$. Again, we have $F(c) < F(y)$. Thus, $0 = F(c) \ge F(x) \ge 0$, which contradicts that $F$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Comment: How to you know that $F(c)=0$ ? If $x$ is a discontinuous point we know that $P(X=x)>0$ i.e. $F(x)-F(x^{-})>0.$

Comment: @AlexHF $c$ is chosen such that $F$ is continuous at $c$, thus $F(c)$ is either 0 or 1. But, due $F(c) < F(y) \le 1$, it must be 0.

Comment: I completely forgot that $F(x)$ is either $0$ or $1$ hihi. Thanks a lot.